# Why am I getting no import suggestions in my React Project in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I am trying to figure out why I am getting no intelliSense suggestions or import suggestions
I am following along with a youtube video to build a react portfolio website and his suggestions are giving him the import from react-router-dom while my suggestions are giving me nothing I have looked at other questions regarding auto-imports as well as trying to fix my intelliSense problems and most of them have to do with creating a jsconfig.json file and putting in compiling options but that did not work and, in his project, he does not have that file so how can I get those suggested imports? [image: My project not giving me any intelisense suggestions]

[image: YouTubers project giving him the react-router-dom suggestion]